# Why there is small hole or opening on the top of a Coolpad Note 3 Lite?

Tags: coolpad-note-3

There is small opening on the top of the rear camera of my Coolpad Note 3 Lite. I was just wondering why it is there; it is quite uncommon for a Coolpad Note 3 Lite, see [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/coolpad_note_3-7655.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost certainly a small microphone for use when recording video using the rear camera. These small holes are quite common on phones and other recording devices to allow a cheap small microphone access to the outside.

Comment: Thankyou Ben i am really a newbie in this field, i recently got to know about rear mics along with cameras btw Thanks for your instant response